# Twig form_theme _self customizing individual field

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a view where I'm trying to override the form theme for an individual field per http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field.

The view looks something like this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _my_form_foo_widget %}
    <div class="input-append">
        {{ block('number_widget') }}
        <span class="add-on">%</span>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

<form>
    {{ form_row(form.foo) }}
    {{ form_row(form.bar) }}
</form>
```

Everything looks as expected for the foo and bar rows, however, the `_my_form_foo_widget` block itself is also included in the output, i.e.:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <span class="add-on">%</span>
</div>

<form>
    <div>
        <label for="my_form_foo">Bar</label>
        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" id="my_form_foo" name="my_form[foo]">
            <span class="add-on">%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="my_form_bar">Foo</label>
        <input type="text" id="my_form_bar" name="my_form[bar]">
    </div>
</form>
```

I can't for the life of my figure out what I'm doing wrong.  As a workaround I just wrapped the block in HTML comments.

I'm on Symfony 2.4.1 and Twig 1.15.0.

Comment: did you clear your cache? Maybe it's a twig parsing error related to the `%` sign. Have you tried changing the `%` in the `<span>` to a different character (i.e. `+`) yet? If that works you could try replacing the `%` with `{{ '%' }}`. Further you could try to move the overriding block to a distinct template (i.e. `form_theme.html.twig` ) and use `{% form_theme form 'form_theme.html.twig' %}`

Comment: @nifr Clearing the cache and changing the `%` to something else makes no difference.

Comment: you did not try my suggestion with the external form_theme :) you're not extending another template - that's why the block gets rendered directly.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to use an external form_theme.  I wanted to be able to put the "one-off" type row/widget customizations in the same file as their form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are experiencing `twig`'s expected behaviour.

A newly defined block is being rendered directly in the current template if you're not **extending** another template.

---

Example:

`template_A.html.twig`:

- has a body (= code outside of blocks) => blocks rendered directly

---

```
<html>
<body>
{% block content -%}
Foo
{%- endblock -%} 

Bar

{%- block more_content -%}
Foo
{%- endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

=> ouputs: `FooBarFoo` ( all blocks present in the template + body is being rendered )

---

Example:

`template_B.html.twig`:

- extending template is not allowed to have a body
- will only render blocks that are present in `template_A.html.twig`

---

```
{% extends 'templateA.html.twig' %} 

{% block content -%}
Bar
{%- endblock %}

{% block not_in_template_a %}
Some String
{% endblock %}
```

=> outputs: `BarBarFoo`     (but does **not** render `Some String` because the block `not_in_template_a` was not present in the original template)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up creating a template with a single, empty block and inherited from that.

I would argue that Symfony's example in their documentation on this is misleading (or just plain incorrect).

Comment: Yeah, I think it should be better documented: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5475