# Overriding the label of a single form field to include HTML in Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, twig, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony-4.4

I am having issues overriding a label in my form in my Symfony 4.4 application:

```
{{ form_row(form.legal, {
   'label' : 'personal.form.fields.legal'|trans
}) }}
```

`personal.form.fields.legal` looks like this:

`I agree that I am 18 and above, I have read and accept the <a href="/terms-cond">T&Cs</a>`

My form definition:

```
 ->add('legal', CheckboxType::class,
   'required' => true,
   'mapped' => false,
])
```

My attempt at overriding this label is this:

```
{% block _crmbundle_personal_legal_label %}
    <label{% with { attr: label_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %} style="color: red;">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ label|unescape|raw }}
    </label>
{%- endblock %}
```

I have a Twig extension that does this:

```
    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('unescape', function ($value) {
                return html_entity_decode($value);
            }),
        ];
    }
```

I am finding this duplicates the label and I can't find a way to correct this. I have one checkbox, but two labels (both showing in red)

Comment: Are you using `CheckboxType` or `ChoiceType` with the `expanded: true` and `multiple: true` option? Also what is your `{% form_theme %}` tag?

Comment: @WillB. Thanks for the comment. I'm using `CheckboxType` and have updated the question with my form field defintion. I have `{% form_theme form _self %}` at the top of the template.

Comment: To prevent the duplicate rendering of the block you need to move your `{% block _crmbundle_personal_legal_label %}` to a separate file than that of the `{{ form_start(form) }}` and set `{% form_theme form 'path/to/form.theme.twig' %}` and optionally extend a base Symfony form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig form\_theme \_self customizing individual field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422038/twig-form-theme-self-customizing-individual-field)